# Calculating the limit of the sum.

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried calculating the sum:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}\:( \frac{1}{n+1} +  \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3}+.......+ \frac{1}{n+n})
$$

using the Sandwich Theorem, however only got that the limit is between $0.5$ and $1$, and was unable to go further with it...? Are there other approaches here?

Answer (score 5):

Hint :

$$\rm L = \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x} \rm dx$$

Answer (score 4):

write
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞} \left( \frac{1}{1+\frac1n} +  \frac{1}{1+\frac2n} + \frac{1}{1+\frac3n}+.......+ \frac{1}{1+\frac nn} \right)\frac1n$$
and use riemann sum.

Comment: You can use `\left(` and `\right)`. This will automatically adjust the size of brackets according to their content.

Comment: @JaideepKhare how?

Comment: See my edit in your post

Comment: thank you sir . . .

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$

The limit is $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx$

Answer (score 1):

By [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence)

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{n}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\sim \ln 2n-\ln n= \ln 2$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{1}{m}\stackrel{\text{def}}=H_{k}=\log k+\gamma+o(1)
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler Mascheroni Constant. Hence
$$
\sum_{m=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{m}=H_{2n}-H_{n}=\log(2n)+\gamma-\log(n)-\gamma+o(1)\stackrel{n\to\infty}\rightarrow \log(2)
$$
since
$$
\log(2n)-\log(n)=\log 2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Other way.**
We can show this identity

$$ \sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac{1}{k+n} =\sum^{2n}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} .   $$

So by the $ln$ series we have

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=ln(2)$$

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies only on straightforward arithmetic along with knowledge of the Taylor series $\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{k}$.

---

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+n}&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k -\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac1{2k}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\tag1
\end{align}$$

Using the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{k}$, we see that

$$\log(2)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\tag2$$

Finally, letting $n\to \infty$ in $(1)$, we see from $(2)$ that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k+n}=\log(2)$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.